# How to log every output from my code using Python?

Tags: python, logging

I wanted my code to include all and every message it gets from the functions in the log file. For example,

```
[2022-07-28 17:49:36,108] {connectionpool.py line:971} DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): "url"
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1013: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host ''. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
```

This is the error I get when running my code, but the output file only logs:

```
[2022-07-28 17:49:36,108] {connectionpool.py line:971} DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): "url"
```

I wanted it to log the WARNING message in the output file.

The code I am using:

```
import logging

file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename=LOG_FILENAME)
stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
handlers = [file_handler, stdout_handler]

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG, 
    format='[%(asctime)s]'" CALLER:"+caller+' {%(filename)s'+" line"+':%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    handlers=handlers
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, Tom. Unfortunately the message I wanted to include in the file is still not being recorded.